# React Native Testing Library shows a warning for using `waitFor`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

I have this test with Jest and react-native-testing-library

```
it('submits form on submit button press', async () => {
  const onSubmit = jest.fn();
  const values = { username: 'jack' };
  const { getByRole } = render(
    <Form initialValues={values} onSubmit={onSubmit} />,
  );

  const button = getByRole('button');

  fireEvent.press(button);

  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(onSubmit).toBeCalledWith(values, expect.anything());
  });
});
```

It passes, but it throws this warning

```
Warning: You seem to have overlapping act() calls, this is not supported. Be sure to await previous act() calls before making a new one.
```

NOTE: if I remove `waitFor` the warning goes aways but the test fails because it doesn't call the `onSubmit` function immediatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing Jest preset from `"react-native"` to `"@testing-library/react-native"` solved the problem.